# Java Twitter Client with Scribe (1st time using it). How to post status? 

Tags: java, twitter, scribe

I'm just starting to use Scribe Library to update my Twitter status.

When I read many pages telling me that 
Scribe library known as Twitter Library, 
So, I dig deep into the [GitHub of the Scribe](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/wiki/getting-started) library, but I ended up with a confused head.

Especially with this [Example file](https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/TwitterExample.java).
If you've opened it, you'll see this line of code:

```
Verifier verifier = new Verifier(in.nextLine());
```

1) The user need to input the PIN code? At the first time I tried to follow the example yes. I understand that we need to grant the access of the java app. But for the next... should we always entering the PIN code?

My purpose is only posting a new tweet... Could we get the Verifier PIN not from the Browser? From the API perhaps?

CMIIW.

Comment: If you noticed, it's an **EXAMPLE** on **HOW** to use Scribe. You have to understand how the example works.

Comment: sorry, sorry, now i just understand how the example worked. Topic edited. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pin code is used in the OOB (Out of Band) flow. The other (normal) flow is providing a callback url where you get the redirect with the verifier, you can do this using the `callback("http://your-host/url")` method on the `ServiceBuilder`.

You can (and are encouraged to) save the access_token so you don't need to authenticate your users every time.

Comment: hey thanks for replying.
CallBack? Is it necessary if it is for my desktop app...? what the things I should have if I use a java app to store userid and pass of twitter account and then using OAuth as your Scribe library does?

my purpose is only posting tweet from the dekstop app, Pablo. :D

Comment: if you have a desktop app you should use the OOB approach (no callback). Open a browser, redirect your users to the `authorizeUrl` and then get the verifier back. With that get the access_token and store it safely. The `TwitterExample` you mention will do well as a starting point

Comment: Is the Out of Band flow similar if I am using a mobile device? Do the user need to input a Verifier?